# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, linker-errors, dynamic-linking, boost-build

I'm trying to link the shared library of boost thread into my application.

System: Windows8

IDE: Visual Studio 2010

I build the boost library using:

```
b2 --with-thread --build-type=complete link=shared
```

I can see the

```
boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll
boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
```

and other file inside the stage/lib directory

I've added the path to Additional Library Directories and Input in linker option as:

Additional Library Directories: `C:/boost_1_55_0_dyn/stage/lib`

Input: `C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib`

I don't know why on the earth Visual Studio is looking for libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib. I haven't mentioned the libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib anywhere in the properties or any place. I even search all my files and folders inside the project, libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Project + Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library setting.  Use /MD to match your link=shared bjam command.  If you want /MT then you also need to build boost with link=static

Comment: @Hans Passant ...and `runtime-link=static`.

Comment: @IgorR. what does runtime-link=static has to do with shared library?

Comment: It has to do with *static* runtime linking.

Comment: well If i wanted static linking, i wouldn't even have put this question here. anyway I got solution to the problem already. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I forgot to put BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK in preprocessor definition. If the BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK is not defined, boost looks for static library, that is why its looking for  libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib

Comment: After putting `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` in `pre-processor in Project + Properties, C/C++,pre-processor, pre-processor definitions` still got error `fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib'`

Comment: To add to it, this error will happen even if you simply include the library directory, but don't actually use any of the libraries. I was having this error thrown on boost_system even though I wasn't even using it.

Answer (score 1):

This is additional information to the answer Pritesh already posted, but I'm new here so I can't comment.

It boils down to compatibility between your VS project settings and the way the boost libraries were built.  It gets a little tricky because boost and VS do some autolinking for you. Check out the file …\Include\boost\config\Auto_link.hpp.  It explains the algorithms and macros that will cause libraries that you didn't explicitly include to show up in your project.

For example, BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK is used to help determine if the boost library name should have "lib" pre-pended to the name during autolink.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally ,

If you are using cmake and qibuild you can try this :

It automatically links with the corresponding libraries and make their headers available.

```
qi_use_lib(yourProgramName your libraries)
```

like this:

```
qi_use_lib(getimages ALCOMMON ALPROXIES ALVISION OPENCV2_CORE OPENCV2_HIGHGUI OPENCV2_IMGPROC)
```